# Regular Expressions to validade Prefix, Infix and Postfix expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I need to create a program in C# that converts an Infix expression into Prefix and Postfix, Prefix expression into Postfix and Infix, Postfix expression into Infix and Prefix. This is not the problem though, the "processing part" of the program is already done.

What I need now is a regular expression to verify if the user input is an Infix, Prefix or Postfix expression, so depending on the input I call a different function to perform the conversions.

The input will always be:
For operands: capital single letters from A to Z
For operators: +, -, * and /

For the Infix expression I made this regular expression (which seems to be working fine):
`"^(([A-Z])(([+]|[-]|[*]|[/])([A-Z]))*)$"`

But I extinguished my ideas trying to make a regular expression for Prefix and Postfix expressions. I also found nothing on internet.
Could someone give me a light?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the patterns will only be used to find out which notation is being used, there's no need to capture any part of the expression in capture groups? Also, is it intended that your pattern doesn't allow for any whitespace? Is prefix notation supposed to look like `+AB` or `+A B`?

Comment: @Rawing Hi. Yes, I only need to find out which notation is being used. And it should not have whitespaces, so I'm considering `+AB` instead of `+A B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible without recursive regex (which C# doesn't support). While (well-formed) infix notation can be matched with the simple regex `[A-Z](?:[*/+-][A-Z])*`, pre- and postfix notation don't follow such a simple pattern that they could be matched by non-recursive regex.

That said, a very simple way to determine if an expression uses pre-/postfix notation (without verifying its correctness) is to check whether the first/last character is an operator: `^[*/+-]` would match a well-formed prefix expression and `.*[*/+-]$` a well-formed postfix expression.

Comment: Hey, do you know how would it be using recursive regex?

Comment: @MatheusSousa: `(?(DEFINE)(?<number>[A-Z])(?<op>[*\/+-](?&expr)(?&expr))(?<expr>(?&number)|(?&op)|\((?&expr)\)))(?&expr)` for prefix, `(?(DEFINE)(?<number>[A-Z])(?<op>(?&expr)(?&expr)[*\/+-])(?<expr>(?&number)|(?&op)|\((?&expr)\)))(?&expr)` for postfix. (Both patterns allow parentheses. If you don't want that, remove the `|\((?&expr)\)` part.)